# Allow any arguments for a given command with sudo

Tags: linux, security, sudo

I have the following sudo config entry which I added via `sudo visudo`:

```
mark ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/lxc-ls*
```

I can run `lxc-ls` with my user fine but I can't append any parameters without it demanding I prefix the command with `sudo`.

```
$ whoami
mark
$ lxc-ls
test-container
$ lxc-ls --fancy
lxc-ls: error: You must be root to access advanced container properties. Try running: sudo /usr/bin/lxc-ls
```

Any idea how I can edit via `sudo visudo` to allow for any argument after the command?

I don't want to prefix the command with sudo as I'm using a python library to execute the command and it's being funny about sudo prefixes.

Update:

I've tried removing the `*` but that didn't work either:

```
$ sudo grep '\-ls' /etc/sudoers
mark ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/lxc-ls
$ lxc-ls
test-container
$ lxc-ls --fancy
...
lxc-ls: error: You must be root to access advanced container properties. Try running: sudo /usr/bin/lxc-ls
```

Comment: This looks perfectly normal to me, **perhaps you should read the information provided more carefully**, they're sure to contain information that is pertinent to your current issue.

Comment: Agree.  This is definitely not off-topic and shows an understanding of the problem (as shown by the fact that people were able to respond).  If the OP's misunderstood the `sudo` syntax fine, but there's no reason to close the bloody topic.

Comment: BTW - I put a space between the * and the command, and that seems to have sorted it for me. See also [this question on superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/167631/fine-grained-sudoers-configuration-allowed-commandline-arguments)  But you do have to run with sudo for it to work of course :)

Answer (score 10):

From the [sudoers manual](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html) :

> A simple file name allows the user to run the command with any
>   arguments he/she wishes

So, drop the *.

You will still need to prefix the lxc-ls command with sudo or write a simple wrapper that does it for you.

Comment: No joy, I've edited my question showing the output.

Comment: Reading is fundamental.

Comment: The sudoers manual is long, complex, and not well organized. There is no example to cover this common use case. The quoted sentence is in the middle of a paragraph. It's extremely reasonable to miss it.

Answer (score 6):

That's not how `sudo` works. The sudoers file simply grants the user rights to a command *when prefixed by the sudo command*, not so you can run it without the sudo being prefixed. You'd need to write a wrapper script (like a simple bash file) to execute the command if your own script can't do it.